# Best Practice for Linq Where with OR clause?

Tags: c#, linq

Ive found using Linq, to do a WHERE selector with multiple clauses separated with an 'AND' is easy peasy - however ive written the below code to do the equivilent of a 'WHERE' query with an 'OR' seperating each case.

Can anyone suggest anything better as it feels abit crappy to concat each time.

```
    var foo = new int[] { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
    var bar = new int[] { 0, 2 };

    var hum = new List<int>();

    foreach (int i in bar)
        hum.AddRange(foo.Where(a => a == i));
```

edit: Changed concat for AddRange...

Comment: I think it might be easier if you rephrase the question.  Don't focus on "how do I do OR", think about, "what am I trying to do".  In this case, "Give me all numbers from foo if the number is also in bar" leads you quickly to the answer Jon posted.  However, since that's specific to the code snippet you posted, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Curious, are you trying to:
1. Set up a bunch of where clauses
2. See if the collection matches any of the clauses
Just trying to get a handle on the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, that code won't even work. `Concat` doesn't modify the sequence it's called on - it returns a new sequence which is the concatenation of two others.

In this case I *think* you want:

```
var values = foo.Where(x => bar.Contains(x));
```

That's specific to this case, of course - there's no "general" OR clause in LINQ.

Comment: Sorry, I cant just do Contains() because there are multiple instances of the foo collection being filtered at different stages.

Comment: @maxp: Well it's not clear what your comment means *or* what you're looking for. Unless you're clear in your requirements, it's hard to give you an answer which will help.

Comment: Why not use a method-group conversion: `foo.Where(bar.Contains)`?

Comment: @Ani: I tend not to even think of using method group conversions, I have to admit. To be honest, I actually find the lambda expression easier to read at a glance, but the method group conversion is still a nice option to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
var hum = bar.Select(x => foo.Where(y => y == x)).SelectMany(z => z).ToList();
```